# Regex to match all until blank line in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

What I am trying to accomplish is matching all text as well as blank lines in a file until it finds a completely blank line. The text itself looks something like this:

> ===Substantiv===
>
> Det var en gång en liten höna som gick på bio, fast det visste hon inte först.
>   Alltså visste hon inte.
>   Fast ändå var det ganska roligt för henne.
>
> ==Annat==
>
> Trots att det var roligt var det inte det.

What I would like to match is everything from "===Substantiv===" to the blank line just above "==Annat==". Since there happen to be more lines with three equal signs, I would also like the code to be somewhat easy to change to another word rather than "===Substantiv===".

What I have tried so far, using regex, is something like:

```
===Adjektiv(.|\n)+
```

But as you can probably tell from the structure of that, there is no absolute way to end it upon locating a blank line, since that will go on forever until the very end of the text I would like to match.

Best regards,

Comment: What do you mean by "blank line" and "completely blank line"? What is the difference?

Comment: I wonder if splitting by 2 new lines will work for you, something like: `str.split('\n\n')` avoiding regex.

Comment: Please never use `(.|\n)+` - it is a highly inefficient pattern. Besides, in JS, `.` does not match `\r`. Use `[\s\S]` or `[^]` to match *any char* incl. line break chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/===Substantiv===(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*)/g
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n5Q8F8/1), your value is inside Group 1. You may trim it after a match is found.

The `.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*` part captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than line break chars (`.*`), then zero or more occurrences (due to `(?:...)*`) of a line break sequence (`\r\n` or `\n` - see `\r?\n`) that is not followed with another line break sequence (see the negative lookahead `(?!\r?\n)`) and then any 0+ chars other than line break symbols.

Note it is an unrolled variant of

```
/===Substantiv===([\s\S]*?)(?=(?:\r?\n){2}|$)/g
```

which is slower than the above pattern, but looks a bit more readable. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DmAsje/1). Here, `([\s\S]*?)` captures any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first double line break (`(?:\r?\n){2}`) or the end of string (`$`).

If by a *blank* line you mean a line that may contain tabs, spaces, etc. you may use

```
/===Substantiv===(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*\r?\n).*)*)/g
                               ^^^
```

or

```
/===Substantiv===(.*(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*\r?\n).*)*)/g
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/n5Q8F8/2)

JS demo:

```js
var regex = /===Substantiv===(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*\r?\n).*)*)/g;
var str = "===Substantiv===\nDet var en gång en liten höna som gick på bio, fast det visste hon inte först.\nAlltså visste hon inte.\nFast ändå var det ganska roligt för henne.\n\n  \n==Annat==\nTrots att det var roligt var det inte det.";
var res = [], m;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
   res.push(m[1].trim());
}
console.log(res);
// Getting all but the matches above
var regex = /===Substantiv===.*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*\r?\n).*)*/;
console.log(str.split(regex).filter(Boolean));
```

**Another idea to get all `Substantiv`s substrings: splitting with a line break and filter the matches**:

```js
var regex = /\r?\n\s*\r?\n/;
var str = "===Substantiv===\nDet var en gång en liten höna som gick på bio, fast det visste hon inte först.\nAlltså visste hon inte.\nFast ändå var det ganska roligt för henne.\n\n  \n==Annat==\nTrots att det var roligt var det inte det.\n\n===Substantiv===\nAnother substantive";
var res = str.split(regex).filter(function (m) {return m.startsWith("===Substantiv===");}).map(function (x) {return x.substr(16).trim();});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: How would one go about selecting all except that in which you selected so very nicely?

Comment: Replace using those regexps with an empty string. Or split and remove empty elements. But you need to get rid of the capture group if you want to use split. I added some JS code to show how to use matching and splitting.

Comment: Would it be possible use something like a regex "not"? Perhaps by somehow using the "^".

Comment: `^` does not just means *not*. It only means *not* in character classes. `[^aeu]` matches all single chars other than `a`, `e`, `u`, and `[^not]` matches `5`, `&` - all chars other than `n`, `o`, `t`. Use splitting.

Comment: And there is no alternative as to matching all except a regex?

Comment: Here, matching all except a regex = split with the regex. There is another approach - a tempered greedy token, but it is not a good idea I think, as it will be even more unreadable and resource consuming.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest simply splitting by empty lines (`/^$/igm`).

If empty lines can occur in the textblock this method will not be good.

```js
//Load string
var str = "===Substantiv===\nDet var en gång en liten höna som gick på bio, fast det visste hon inte först.\nAlltså visste hon inte.\nFast ändå var det ganska roligt för henne.\n\n==Annat==\nTrots att det var roligt var det inte det.";

//Split by empty line
var str = str.split(/^$/igm);

//Optional trimming
str = str.map(function(a) {
  return a.toString().trim();
})

//Log results
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  console.log(str[i]);
}
```

If you only need the string containing `===Substantiv===`:

```js
//Load string
var str = "===Substantiv===\nDet var en gång en liten höna som gick på bio, fast det visste hon inte först.\nAlltså visste hon inte.\nFast ändå var det ganska roligt för henne.\n\n==Annat==\nTrots att det var roligt var det inte det.";

//Split by empty line
var str = str.split(/^$/igm);

//Optional trimming
str = str.map(function(a) {
  return a.toString().trim();
});

//Filtering
str = str.filter(function(a){
  return a.toString().indexOf('===Substantiv===') >= 0;
})

//Log results
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  console.log(str[i]);
}
```